# Get response from JWT auth API in IOS application using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

1. I have a situation to get access token from API: 35.163.73.115:5000/api/AccountForInterviews/GetAuthKey. I have username and password with me but when I tried to get response using objective c I got an error message as unsupported url. What is the process to fetch data from the services like above in objective c.
2. API:35.163.73.115:5000/api/Interviews/GetList. I need to get list for the authenticated user but don't know how to handle JWT auth to fetch data for the services like I mentioned.

in my ViewController I have following statements

```
NSDictionary* dict = @{ @"accessToken": [jsonObject objectForKey:@"accessToken"]};
        NSError *anError;
        NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&anError];
[[WebServiceHandler sharedHandler] postData:data toURLString:@"http://35.163.73.115:5000/api/Interviews/GetList" callBackCompletionHandler:^(id jsonObject, NSError *anotherError) {
        NSLog(@"List Json::%@, err::%@", jsonObject, anotherError);
    }];
```

I got following error.
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.

Comment: Did you wrote `http://` before? What's your code when you write that?

Comment: Client gave me like I mentioned above, but I added https://, then I got an SSL error.

Comment: Could you give your code? Add `http://` maybe instead if it doesn't supports `https://`

Comment: Your code, what's your code?

Comment: Edit your question with that code. Give also the code of `fetchDataforURLString`.

Comment: Edit your question with that code. It's unreadable in comment. My guess? `NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];` is nil. That's what is causing the issue.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, except http....it's working with http, Thank you @Larme. what about API:35.163.73.115:5000/api/Interviews/GetList. I need to get list for the authenticated user but don't know how to handle JWT auth to fetch data for the services like I mentioned.